# Python- How to apply dot product between elements of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames. Both have one column of numpy arrays with 3 elements per entry, like so:

```
0             [0.552347, 0.762896, 0.336009]
1             [0.530716, 0.808313, 0.254895]
2             [0.528786, 0.734991, 0.424469]
3            [0.202799, 0.669395, -0.714691]
4           [0.791936, -0.100072, -0.602347]
6             [0.428896, -0.122712, 0.89498]
```

How do I take the dot product of each row of one data frame with the corresponding row of the other data frame? Meaning, I want to calculate the dot product of the first element of df1 with the first element of df2, then the second element of df1 with the second element of df2, then third, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(np.array([0.552347, 0.762896, 0.336009]), ), 
                    (np.array([0.530716, 0.808313, 0.254895]), )], columns=['v1'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([(np.array([0.528786, 0.734991, 0.424469]), ), 
                    (np.array([0.202799, 0.669395, -0.714691]), )], columns=['v2'])

pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1).apply(lambda row: row.v1.dot(row.v2), axis=1)

0    0.995420
1    0.466538
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they are same length of df1 , df2

```
[x.dot(y) for x, y in zip(df1.col1.values,df2.col1.values)]
Out[648]: [0.9999995633060001, 1.00000083965]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty fast to calculate dot products manually. For this you can use `mul` and `sum` if the 2 dataframes share the same index:

```
df1.col.mul(df2.col).apply(sum)
```

If they don't share the same index (but are the same length), use `reset_index` first:

```
df1.reset_index().col.mul(df2.reset_index().col).apply(sum)
```

**Example**:

```
>>> df1
         col
0  [0, 1, 2]
1  [3, 4, 5]
>>> df2
         col
0  [5, 6, 7]
1  [1, 2, 3]

>>> df1.col.mul(df2.col).apply(sum)
0    20
1    26
```